# Country representation with hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, dao, hibernate-annotations

I'm in the process of migrating my JDBC project to Hibernate.
I have a question regarding reference data stored in my DB, in perticular it's the UN country list.
I took it from [here](http://devsushi.com/2007/04/14/country-list-formatted-for-mysql-import/).

When I was using JDBC, I just had a table that hold that data, and I used to use it to validate the data in the DB. for instance, a user couldn't enter that he lives in a country which didn't exist in that table.

Now, I have the Pojo that represents a person, and I have a string member which represents a country, how do I persist it with Hibernate, do I need to create a Pojo for country ?
How can I reference the below code to a "reference table" which isn't a pojo ?

```
@OneToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "country_iso")
private String country;
```

the above code, is what I started to write, but I don't know if this is the way to do it.

Comment: now I'm more confusd then before...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think it's a good idea to create a class `Country`, using the iso code as id.

You need to setup a many-to-one relation as many persons can exist in one country.

Country:

```
@Id
String id;
```

Person:

```
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name="COUNTRY", referencedColumnName="ID") 
Country country;
```

In that way, you can load all countries as a collection using Hibernate, and you can set up rules for the relation (like optional=false, etc)

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest you create an entity for Country like

```
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import org.hibernate.annotations.Cache;
import org.hibernate.annotations.CacheConcurrencyStrategy;

@Entity
@org.hibernate.annotations.Entity(mutable=false) //since this table is supposed to
@Table(name="Countries")
@Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.READ_ONLY)
public class Country{
@Id
String ccode;
String name;
}
```

with this mapping, you map Country pojo to table countries, and also set this entity to immutable and enabled 2L cache as well (this is the best case to enable 2L cache with readonly strategy )

Comment: Sounds interesting, how exactly does the 2L read only cache strategy works ?

Answer (score 1):

In this type of situations you can follow the below approach. I am presuming that you will not be inserting the `Country` table at run-time.

Have a field for countryId in the `Person` class.

```
@Column(name = "country_iso")
private String countryId;
```

when you want to save the `Person` to the database **get the countryId depending on the country name(from the database) and set it to countryId of the `Person`. Then save the `Person`.**

You can have a POJO for `Country` and refer it in `Person` class if need.